# Como fazer um gráfico de perfis no R?

Tags: r

Eu estou tentando criar uma gráfico de perfis para esse quadro de dados que intitulei "Femi":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o código dos dados:

```
structure(list(oito = c(21, 21, 20.5, 23.5, 21.5, 20, 21.5, 23, 
20, 16.5, 24.5), dez = c(20, 21.5, 24, 24.5, 23, 21, 22.5, 23, 
21, 19, 25), doze = c(21.5, 24, 24.5, 25, 22.5, 21, 23, 23.5, 
22, 19, 28), catorze = c(23, 25.5, 26, 26.5, 23.5, 22.5, 25, 
24, 21.5, 19.5, 28)), .Names = c("oito", "dez", "doze", "catorze"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Cada observação é uma criança, que foi observada aos 8, 10, 12 e 14 anos de idade.

Consegui fazer o seguinte gráfico: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso agora inserir linhas que liguem cada observação feita no mesmo indivíduo, traçando assim um perfil de cada individuo a medida que a sua idade muda.

Comment: Cloves, ao invés de uma imagem, poste seus dados usando o comando `dput`. O código que você usou também é recomendado, apesar de eu achar que não será necessário nesse caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando os `dplyr`, `tidyr` e `ggplot2` você pode fazer assim:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
dados %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(idade, distancia, -id) %>%
  mutate(idade = factor(idade, levels = c("oito", "dez", "doze", "catorze"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = idade, y = distancia, group = id)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]